# get data from customize listview

Tags: android, listview

Here is my code,

```
public class SecondScreenActivity extends Activity {
ListView foodJntListView;
ArrayList<Restaurent> restaurentData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_screen);

    restaurentData = getFoodJnt();

    foodJntListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_foodjnt);
    foodJntListView.bringToFront();

    // setting the adapter to the list 
    foodJntListView.setAdapter(new RestaurantBaseAdapter(this,restaurentData));

    //setting the onclick listener,activity on clicking on an item of the 
    foodJntListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String hotelname=restaurentData.get(position).toString();
             //things to write
        }
    });
}

// get all the list of foodjoints

private ArrayList<Restaurent> getFoodJnt() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Restaurent> results=new ArrayList<Restaurent>();

    Restaurent restrnt=new Restaurent();

    restrnt.setFoodJointname("Ashila");
    restrnt.setCuisine("Biriyani,Moughlai");
    restrnt.setAddress("Kolkata,E M Bypass");
    restrnt.setOpenhours("10:00am-10:00pm");
    results.add(restrnt);

    restrnt=new Restaurent();
    restrnt.setFoodJointname("Bhajohori Manna");
    restrnt.setCuisine("Bengali,Chinese");
    restrnt.setAddress("Kolkata,Esplanede");
    restrnt.setOpenhours("10:00am-10:00pm");
    results.add(restrnt);

    restrnt=new Restaurent();
    restrnt.setFoodJointname("Bar B Q");
    restrnt.setCuisine("Bengali,Chinese,Thai");
    restrnt.setAddress("Kolkata,Park Street");
    restrnt.setOpenhours("10:00am-10:00pm");
    results.add(restrnt);

    return results;
}


public void makeAToast(String str) {
    //yet to implement
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
```

I can able to show a customized listview with a bunch of textview on it as it's item but,I want to get the Name of the restauirants setOnItemClick on the List view.

e.g whenever I click Click on "Bar B Q","calcutta Food Court",it'll show me only "Bar B Q","calcutta Food Court" not other informations.
thnx in advance.Feel free to if u need anything.

[image]"my application screen shot"

Comment: I think is your code is right. What are you getting in 'hotelname' onItemClick??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume you've got method like `getFoodJointname()` in your `Restaurent` class, you can write the below in your `onItemClick()`:

```
String hotelname = restaurentData.get(position).getFoodJointname();
makeAToast(hotelname);
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work hopefully.

```
Restaurent rest= (Restaurent) foodJntListView.getSelectedItem();
```